# Connect to a service in another pod in same namespace without using namespace in URL

Tags: kubernetes

How to access a service from another pod in same namespace without using namespace name in URL?

Can't use this as it is using namespace name in url.
`<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Reason: namespace names are dynamic in my setup and not in my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just directly use the other Service name as a host name if you know it's in the same namespace as your Pod.

```
http://<service-name>/path
```

[DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) documents that both `svc.cluster.local` and `<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` are added to the default DNS search path (in the container's `/etc/resolv.conf` file), which makes this work.